# Windows store xaml and c# how to create accordian style list

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a ListView IsGroupedSource is set to true in it's CollectionViewSource. I'm trying to toggle a groups visibility when it's group header is clicked.

```
<CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="FiltersViewSource"
        Source="{Binding Filters}"
        IsSourceGrouped="true"
        ItemsPath="AttributeValues"
        />

<ListView
                    x:Name="filtersListView"
                    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemListView"
                    AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"                      
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Margin="0,-10,0,0"
                    Padding="30"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource FiltersViewSource}}"
                    SelectionMode="None"
                    IsSwipeEnabled="false"
                    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                    ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">
                    <ListView.GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Margin="7,7,0,0">
                                        <Button AutomationProperties.Name="Group Title"
                                            Click="Header_Click"
                                            Style="{StaticResource TextPrimaryButtonStyle}">
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="White" FontSize="35" Margin="3,-7,10,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}" />
                                                <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ChevronGlyph}" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Margin="0,-7,0,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Button>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </GroupStyle.Panel>
                        </GroupStyle>
                    </ListView.GroupStyle>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                                <StackPanel  Visibility="{Binding Visibility}" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <CheckBox Margin="0,0,20,0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource ItemTextStyle}" Foreground="White" FontSize="20" MaxHeight="40"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="(40)" Style="{StaticResource ItemTextStyle}" Foreground="White" FontSize="25" MaxHeight="40"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

Basically I'm trying to create an accordion style list. I tried adding.

```
<VariableSizedWrapGrid Visibility="{Binding Visibility}" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
```

Visbility is a property of type Visibility in the underlying group object.

But it doesn't work.

Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Comment: can you post code-behind ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try binding the Header Button's Command property to a view model command that changes a group view model Visibility property that you would bind to your VariableSizedWrapGrid.

Comment: I would like to try it but I'm having a hard to understanding what exactly you mean. Can you please explain a little more in detail.

Comment: If i understand what your saying correctly, i already tried that.

Comment: I just tried that myself and it seems like the DataContext of the group panel is not a group itself but some generic DependencyObject instance. Based on that I think you would either need to create some custom behavior that would walk the visual tree to find the correct panel and flip its visibility or stop using the grouping feature of a GridView and instead have a horizontally scrollable ListView where each item is a GridView bound to a group.

Comment: Thank you I tried your second solution "horizontally scrollable ListView where each item is a GridView bound to a group" and it worked very well. Thank You!