# Sliding effect on buttons

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I have a user control which looks like this:

[image: Main user control]

I want to achieve the effect in which when a user clicks on a button, every other button slides side ways and some content according to the clicked button appears in rest of the available space. Something like this:

[image: User clicked on skin tone button]

and this:

[image: User clicked on time button]

How can I achieve this effect? I am working with C# and XAML...

Comment: That's a `ListBox`. What have you tried?

Comment: Look http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: Have no clue what to try... Can you elaborate a bit more about how can I achieve this with listbox?

Comment: Ramesh Rajendran - This is exactly the thing I need but it is in JQuery. How can I do this with XAML and C#?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929515/windows-store-xaml-and-c-sharp-how-to-create-accordian-style-list, and the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) has one as well so you could see how it's done and adapt to Windows 8.  I'm not sure if there's a "Windows Store Toolkit" equivalent in open source, but many component vendors likely have one.  Conceptually it's just a matter of collapsing and showing content, with some animation.

Comment: @JimO'Neil Yeah I did it according to this concept... Thanks for helping